# How many entities do not support simple PATCH of 'status' and 'state' codes?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

For example:
to set an account record to inactive you need to send the request to

```
PATCH https://<hostname>/api/data/v9.0/accounts(000-000-0000-0000)
```

with the body

```
{
  "statecode": 1,
  "statuscode": 2
}
```

but it does not work with the opportunity entity.
To mark it **Won** or **Lost** you should send a request that differs from the above one.
I want to know how many entities do not support a simple request to change their state.

Answer (score 1):

From top of my head, I remember these below scenarios have special dialog and there’s an extra entity where more details will be captured on status change.

1. [Opportunity close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/sales-enterprise/customize-opportunity-close-experience#add-newly-created-custom-fields-to-the-opportunity-close-form) - this is an [activity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/opportunityclose?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)
2. [Case resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/customer-service-hub-user-guide-modify-case-resolution-dialog#case-resolution-entity)
3. [Quote close](https://www.thrives.be/functional/closing-quotes-as-won-without-creating-orders/)

For these scenarios, instead of doing PATCH of statecode/statuscode, we have functions/actions to invoke using sdk/web api. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/use-web-api-actions#unbound-actions)

That being said, I never seen a list or consolidation in the internet for these exceptions. Atleast I gave you a starting point, since there may be more. System user entity is different too. Btw, what are you trying to achieve?